# Selecting rows that meet certain criteria in R

Tags: r

I want to use WHERE function from SQL on data in R. My data look kind of like that (only with much more data so creating vectors is):

```
Year Class Student Points

2008 1  A  67

2008 1  B  73

2008 1  C  43

2012 2  D  23

2012 2  E  93

2012 3  F  55

2012 3  G  78

2014 1 A  93

2014  1  B  65

2008 1  C  50

2012 2  D  30
```

I want to create separated bar chart for students in class 1 and for students tested in 2012 with mean points for class 2 and 3. This problem seems to be very easy but I haven't been able to find it on the Internet yet.
I found functions with numbers, for exmple df[df$value>3.0,], however it does not work with a characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with SQL, you might want to install the `sqldf`-package, which allows to operate on data frames with sql-commands.
For the problem you describe here, you can do something like this 
`df[df$class=='A',]`

When I run your problem, everything works fine:

```
df<-read.csv("test.csv", sep=" ")
df[df$Class==1,]
   Year Class Student Points
1  2008     1       A     67
2  2008     1       B     73
3  2008     1       C     43
8  2014     1       A     93
9  2014     1       B     65
10 2008     1       C     50
```